How may I find my current Ubuntu OS version
I forgot the Ubuntu version that installed in my laptop because I use a dual OS. Where may I find my software version?

In a terminal window type: lsb_release -sd

Alternative way:
$ source /etc/os-release; echo $PRETTY_NAME
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS

or even:
$ . /etc/os-release ; echo $NAME $VERSION
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)


GUI Application: Settings->System Info
